# Platform about panResponder in React JSX

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jsx, react-native-ios

I'm use ReactNative panResponder. I put a NativeView nested in View. The android NativeView have handled the gestureEvent,so ReactNative _panHandlers only need to add in iOS.

About this _panHandlers , is it only this ugly way to separate ios and Android?

```
     if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        return (<View style={styles.container} 
                {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
            <NativeView/>
        </View>);
    } else {
        return (<View style={styles.container}>
            <NativeView/>
        </View>);
    }
```

Is there someway like this style?

```
  <View  style={if (Platform.OS === 'ios')?{}:{}} />
```

And What's mean about  "{...}" in "{...this._panResponder.panHandlers}"?

Answer (score 0):

Just like this when create this object :

```
    this._panResponder = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (e, gestureState) => {
            return false;
        },
        onPanResponderMove: (evt, gs) => {

        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gs) => {

        }
    }) : {};
```

about "{...}" :

[Spread_operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)